# How can I truncate or reduce contents from the end of a file using Rust?

Tags: file, rust

I have a 90MB file. I want to append about 20 bytes of data at the end and also be able to truncate that 20 bytes of appended data afterwards. How can I do this using Rust?

**Update**
I think my question was not very clear so I am going to explain again what I am looking for.
To put it simple I am looking for a function from the `std` lib or whatever library, that could truncate a file at a given size, or remove a give amount of bytes from the end of a file. no need for a full example how to do it.

**Answer**: Thanks @harmic it was that simple still I didn't notice it.

`std::fs::File::set_len` will do the work I think.

Comment: What have you tried? As it is, the question is too broad for us to really answer, because there are several ways to accomplish that. We're here to _help_ you achieve your goals, not write your code for you, so make sure you share code that you've written, even if it doesn't work, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Did you see [File::set_len](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_len)?

Comment: You want to add 20 bytes and then remove 20 bytes. That means you wish to perform no changes to the file, so you don't need to write any code whatsoever. Problem solved.

Comment: I searched the std lib but couldn't find a function to perform truncate on file, that's why I thought it would be better to ask here. Sorry I didn't mention that I won't be removing these bytes at the same time, I want make two functions one for adding some data to the end of the file, and another to remove that data from the end of the file. these functions don't have to be executed at the same timing.@harmic Looks like this is the thing I was looking for, looks like I didn't search enough. thank you for the hint. would you please add it as answer.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster thank you for your comment, I was planning to do it, I am just waiting for **harmic** to post it since it's his answer, if not, I will do it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::fs::File::set_len](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.set_len) will do the work.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should also remember to adjust cursor position after using `set_len()`, as that doesn't move the cursor and it might be in an unexpected position.

Comment: Continuing the above, that'd be `file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0))`.

Comment: @jakub, I think one would expect the cursor to be at the end of the file after this operation, so probably rather `file.seek(SeekFrom::End(0))`

Comment: If the file is empty, isn't Start the same as End? You may be completely right though.