# Overwrite file after reading

Tags: file, rust

I've got a case, when I need to read a file data, do some data processing and write processed data into the file by overwriting it's content.

I tried to use [OpenOptions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) with  `read`, `write` and `truncate` options, but `truncate` option makes file empty before I can read it, `write` option starts writing at the end of the file (appending).

I tried some ways, like [`f.set_len`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585434/12255756), but it sets some unreadable bytes at the beginning of the file with no reason, [`f.rewind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.rewind) just puts writing content before the original file beginning...

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.write):

> `pub fn write(&mut self, write: bool) -> &mut Self`
>
> Sets the option for write access.
>
> This option, when true, will indicate that the file should be
> write-able if opened.
>
> If the file already exists, any write calls on it will overwrite its
> contents, without truncating it.

You should not read the file while writing on it. You may have some options:

1. Read the file content entirely. Close the file process and open again for reading.
2. Read the file, process, and write to another file. When finished overwrite the original one with the new.